# ALTER TABLE ... SWITCHing from regular table to partitioned table fails

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, sql-server-2014

The code below does the following:

1. Creates a database play_partition in C:\TEMP
2. Creates two identical partitioned tables play_table and archive_play_table
3. Switches play_table partition 1 to archive_play_table partition 1
4. Creates a new unpartitioned table temp_table with the same structure as play_table on the same filegroup as play_table partition 2
5. Switches play_table_partition 2 to temp_table
6. Tries to switch temp_table back to play_table partition 2 and fails with

   Msg 4982, Level 16, State 1, Line 64
   ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed. Check constraints of source table 
   'play_partition.dbo.temp_table' allow values that are not allowed by
   range defined by partition 2 on target table
   'play_partition.dbo.play_table'.

Why does it fail?

I am using SQL Server 2014 (Enterprise Edition Trial).

Regards,

Colin Daley

http://www.colindaley.com/translator

```
/* Playing with partitioned tables */

USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE play_partition;
GO

CREATE DATABASE play_partition
    ON PRIMARY(
        NAME = play_partition
        , FILENAME = 'C:\TEMP\play_partition.mdf')
    ,FILEGROUP play_fg1(
        NAME = play_fg1
        ,FILENAME = 'C:\TEMP\play_fg1f1.ndf')
    ,FILEGROUP play_fg2(
        NAME = play_fg2f1
        ,FILENAME = 'C:\TEMP\play_fg2f1.ndf');
GO

USE play_partition;


CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION play_range(INT)
    AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES(3);

-- Partition scheme
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME play_scheme 
    AS PARTITION play_range TO (play_fg1, play_fg2);

-- Partitioned tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.play_table(
    c1 INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_play_table_c1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
    ON play_scheme(c1);

CREATE TABLE dbo.archive_play_table(
c1 INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_archive_play_table_c1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
    ON play_scheme(c1);

-- partition 1 = {1, 2, 3}, partiion 2 = {4, 5, 6}
INSERT INTO dbo.play_table(c1) VALUES (1), (2),  (3), (4), (5), (6);

-- move partition 1 from play_table to archive play_table
ALTER TABLE dbo.play_table
    SWITCH PARTITION 1 to dbo.archive_play_table PARTITION 1;

-- create empty table with same structure as dbo.play_table
SELECT * INTO dbo.temp_table FROM dbo.play_table WHERE 1 = 0;

-- move temp_table to filegroup play_fg2
ALTER TABLE dbo.temp_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_temp_table_c1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(c1) ON play_fg2;

-- move contents of play_table to temp_table, which is not partitioned
-- but is in the same filegroup
ALTER TABLE dbo.play_table
    SWITCH PARTITION 2 TO temp_table;
PRINT 'Switched from partitioned table to non-partitioned table';

-- move data back to partitioned play_table from unpartitioned temp_table
-- FAIL
ALTER TABLE dbo.temp_table
    SWITCH TO play_table partition 2;
PRINT 'Switched from non-partitioned table to partitioned table';


SELECT 'archive_play_table' as table_name, t1.c1
    FROM dbo.archive_play_table AS t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'temp_table' AS table_name, t1.c1
        FROM dbo.temp_table as t1
    ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: +1 on your question.  You made it easy to repro and answer, due to DDL you put here.  For that, thank you.  I wish I could +10 questions like this.

Comment: Thanks. That error needs a better message. When it mentioned check constraints on the table (when there was no check constraint), it did not occur to me that the lack of a check constraint was, in fact, the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are working with partition switching, SQL Server will need to verify that the source table/partition boundaries can fit in the destination table/partition boundaries.  In other words, you're trying to switch data from `dbo.temp_table` to `dbo.play_table`'s partition 2.  Think of it like this, the data for the `c1` in `dbo.temp_table` is constrained only by the data type (`int`), so you can have values ranging from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.  But conversely, you're destination (`dbo.play_table` partition 2) has a range from 4 to 2,147,483,647.

Your data does not violate this, but it is the metadata that can't allow this.  You could just as easily insert the value -10 into `dbo.temp_table`.  The partition switching would fail the same way and make more sense, as -10 does not fit in `dbo.play_table`'s 2nd partition boundaries.

If you wanted to make this code work, you'd need to explicitly tell SQL Server that `dbo.temp_table` will never have any data that won't fit in `dbo.play_table`'s 2nd partition.  You could do this with a check constraint:

```
/******************************************************************************
    your code omitted for brevity
******************************************************************************/

-- move contents of play_table to temp_table, which is not partitioned
-- but is in the same filegroup
ALTER TABLE dbo.play_table
    SWITCH PARTITION 2 TO temp_table;
PRINT 'Switched from partitioned table to non-partitioned table';

/******************************************************************************
    added check constraint so that data can fit in the destination partition
******************************************************************************/
alter table dbo.temp_table
add constraint CK_TempTable_C1 check (c1 >= 4);
go
/******************************************************************************
    end of added code
******************************************************************************/

-- move data back to partitioned play_table from unpartitioned temp_table
-- this will no longer FAIL
ALTER TABLE dbo.temp_table
    SWITCH TO play_table partition 2;
PRINT 'Switched from non-partitioned table to partitioned table';

/******************************************************************************
    your code omitted for brevity
******************************************************************************/
```

That above sample addition to your code makes this a working solution.  Now SQL Server knows that the data in `dbo.temp_table` can fit in partition 2 of `dbo.play_table` because of the added check constraint to `dbo.temp_table`.